# Publish Failed to sign msix

Tags: visual-studio-2019, windows-store, msix

Using Visual Studio 2019 to publish an update to an existing windows store application.  This worked a week ago.

Our solution builds without error.  When I go to create the setup package I get an error "Failed to sign 'D:\dev\MeyerMusic\MeyerTablet\TabletDistribution\bin\AnyCPU\Release\MeyerMusicTabletSetup_2.6.6.0_AnyCPU.msix'."

We are distributing the application as a Microsoft Store app under the existing app name.

Last week on this same development computer I built version 2.6.5 as well as many packages before that.

The error number is blank or missing.  I do not have a reason for the failure.  I only see one fact in the error message and that points to line 4574 in the file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets

That line is this:

```
<SignAppxPackage Condition="'$(AppxPackageSigningEnabled)' == 'true'"
                 AppxPackageToSign="$(AppxMainPackageOutput)"
                 CertificateThumbprint="$(PackageCertificateThumbprint)"
                 CertificateFile="$(PackageCertificateKeyFile)"
                 CertificatePassword="$(PackageCertificatePassword)"
                 HashAlgorithmId="$(AppxHashAlgorithmId)"
                 EnableSigningChecks="$(EnableSigningChecks)"
                 SignAppxPackageExeFullPath="$(SignAppxPackageExeFullPath)"
                 TempCertificateFilePath="$(TempCertificateFilePath)"
                 VsTelemetrySession="$(VsTelemetrySession)"
                 SigningTimestampServerUrl="$(AppxPackageSigningTimestampServerUrl)"
                 SigningTimestampDigestAlgorithm="$(AppxPackageSigningTimestampDigestAlgorithm)"
                     />
```

Troubleshooting steps:

1. Attempted to build a side load package.  Results in same error
2. Successfully built a side load package that was not signed
3. I have restarted Visual Studio
4. I have rebooted the machine
5. I have deleted OBJ, BIN for the entire solution
6. I have looked for errors in the event log but none have been found so far.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 16.4.5.  I had an associate publish from a different machine and it worked.  The only discernible difference is he has Visual Studio Enterprise 16.4.4.  We are both working with the same files from TFS.

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalling KB4535996 the problem was resolved.

I found this via a tip from the following post: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/934967/uwp-error-failed-to-sign.html